# Determining which packet/update arrived first between two machines

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, networking, time, websocket

I have two separate AWS Virtual Machines set up within a region (different availability zones) both are connected via WebSocket (in Python) to a different load balancer (Cloudfront) of the same host server (also hosted with AWS) and receive frequent small WebSocket payloads - every 5ms.

NB: I do not own the host server I am merely on the receiving end.

Both machines are receiving the same updates and I would like to measure on which machine the updates/payloads/packets are arriving first

In essence I would like to figure out which load balancer is "closer" to the host and so has the least latency overhead in transmitting the signal since my application is highly latency sensitive.

I have tried using the system clock to get timestamps of the data arrival however it is not guaranteed that the two instances have their time synced to an appropriate accuracy.

Comment: I would suggest you don't actually care which message arrives first.  Instead, you care which loadbalancer gives you better quality of service.  Measure your quality of service on the two hosts over a number of requests and then choose accordingly.

Comment: Also, providing a total ordering of events that occur on two different computers is Hard.

Comment: But I do care which message arrives first, the messages are currency price updates and so using a delayed message will be detrimental to trading performance.

Comment: So, sounds like you have a QoS metric - which node makes more profitable trades?

Comment: I'm afraid the profit has way too much variance to use as a metric to compare the two.

Comment: If you are on a shared VM, nothing that you measure will make any difference. You will 1) need to drop the load balancer and implement your own setup. 2) drop shared VMs and host on dedicated hardware. 3) Resources in the cloud are shared. The variance of these resources is an order of magnitude larger than the variation of two packets. In addition, one packet may take route A and the next packet may take route B. You have zero control over this unless you control the routers and backbone. If you depend on time, then you will need to timestamp the packets at the sender, not the time received.

Answer (score 1):

follow this.

> 1. Send a request to the load balancer with the body of the request containing the timestamp when it was sent to the server. You can
>      easily do this using the DateTime api of your fav language.
> 2. After that packet arrives to your backend server residing on your instance (can be a simple node server or a rails server), you can get
>      that request, and compare it to the current timestamp.
> 3. You can do this on both the servers and can easily compare which was faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm afraid this won't work since I don't own the host server, I am only on the receiving end. This would also require the front & backend to have their clocks synced perfectly which is something else I am struggling with.

Comment: Well you don't need to know when the request originated. We can compare the arrival time of request on both machines. 

The idea is to note down the receiving time of two consecutive packets. Their difference would give you the difference in arrival time of both packets.

Do this on both the machine and the lowest time received on any of the machine will be the machine closest to the LB+host.

Comment: Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: For example, lets suppose we dont know the request origination time. Lets keep it as X

On both machines we are noting down the time of receival of request.
On machine A it was a and on machine B it was b.

If we consider that request are coming in a regular uniform fashion we can safely assume next packet will also come in about the same time.

Now we can assume the last arrival time on both packets like their origination time as it would not make much difference, assuming packets are generated and sent in the constant same time duration.

Comment: Basically just get the difference in arrival time of two requests on both the machines and lowest candidate will be the combination of LB and client u want to use. :)

Comment: I'm afraid the arrival times aren't regular, the packets contain currency price updates and so come through whenever there is a price change. I don't think that the difference between consecutive updates can help since say B receives the updates 1ms later than A always then the difference  a2-a1 =  ((b2-1) - (b1-1)) = b2-b1 but without providing any information on a1<b1 or a2<b2